# Why does PDB file not copy over to module directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdb-files

A couple of months back I was running into an issue debugging a service I wrote remotely.  I publish everything to the correct directory.  Some how or the other, when I attempt to attach, the debugger tells me that I am missing a pdb file (not in so many words obviously).  So what I do is, I go in and look a the missing modules.  Look for the specific directory on my server, and just copy the pdb directly from the bin file to that directory.  Does anybody know why I have to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you publishing?  Is it asmx or WCF?

Comment: It is indeed WCF.  Well, my publish function doesn't work.  So I just publish to a directory and copy that file to my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't get the pdb file if you build your dll or application in release mode of visual studio.try building the dll in debug mode you will get the pdb file.

Comment: While I get the pdb... But it doesn't appear in the temp file that the remote debugger looks at to load up the module.  Weird.